# About Button Images in WP7

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mobile

I am trying to develop an app for WP7 and I want to change the background image of a button if it is clicked.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `DataTemplate` for `button` like this

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Then you can set the image on button like this in XAML

```
<Button x:Name="button"  Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyImageSource}"></Button>
```

In code behind inside the button click event you can do this to change the background at runtime

```
button.Content = YourImage;
```

Comment: Im sorry Im new in xaml. Where am I gonna paste the xaml code?

Comment: You can paste this code in `resources` section of your page or control whatever you have in your scenario.

Comment: I mean the xaml code that stars with <sytle.... in which container do I have to use that?

Comment: You place that inside a resource container. See this tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-4-using-style-elements-to-better-encapsulate-look-and-feel.aspx or search how to use Style in XAML